# Visual Code Studio error: "Python package 'pandas' version 0.20.0 (or above) is required for viewing data"

Tags: python, pandas, visual-studio-code

I used to be able to view data variables in Visual Code. Recently I keep getting this error "Python package 'pandas' version 0.20.0 (or above) is required for viewing data."

- despite the error message, the installed pandas version IS above 0.20.0. It's 2.2.0 in fact.
- I have uninstalled and re-installed all of these: pandas, numpy and jupyter extension in Visual Code Studio.
- I have updated anaconda

None of the above removes the issue. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe create a new virtual environment then install and try afresh?

Comment: Make sure VS Code is using the correct environment, ie. the one which has pandas installed.

Comment: Hi JialeDu I have solved the issue, the answer is provided below. Thanks

Comment: Also thank you Paddy and Goku - tried both suggestions and they weren't the source of the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for all your prompts- unfortunately they did not work, but this solved the issue:

pip install --upgrade bottleneck

Best,
Fran

Answer (score 2):

You need to install pyarrow , it is a dependency for pandas

https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/install.html

Comment: thank you, this didn't seem to be the issue!

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a `.py` file: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> -->`Python: Select Interpreter`, select the correct interpreter, i.e. the one with *pandas 2.2.0* installed.

[image]

If you are using jupyter: click on the kernel version in the upper right corner and select the one with *pandas 2.2.0* installed.

[image]

Comment: thank you, this didn't seem to be the issue!